# Анимация спрайтов

Tags: javascript, анимация, спрайт

Не могу понять, как исправить мигание анимации((

Сама картинка подобрана не с большим количеством кадров, но вроде как дело не в этом.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('field');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let sx = 0,
  tick_count = 0;
let sprite = new Image();
sprite.src = 'https://ratnotes.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/animal-2a.png';
sprite.onload = function() {
  tick();
  requestAnimationFrame(tick); //вызов анимации
};

function tick() {
  if (tick_count > 10) {
    drawCat();
    tick_count = 0;
  }
  tick_count += 1;
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

function drawCat() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //очистка канваса
  sx = (sx === 384 ? 0 : sx + 96); //переброс в начало, если спрайт закончился 384 - width картинки, 384/4 =96 -шаг, на который сдвигаем
  ctx.drawImage(sprite, sx, 0, 96, 96, 100, 100, 96, 96); //отображение первого спрайта
}
```

```html
<canvas id="field" width="900" height="400">hi</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Четвертый спрайт заканчивается на 288: [0,96,192,288]. Дальше вы рисуете пустой спрайт, который вызывает эффект моргания. Исправьте границу sx: `sx = (sx === 288 ? 0 : sx + 96);`

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('field');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let sx = 0,
  tick_count = 0;
let sprite = new Image();
sprite.src = 'https://ratnotes.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/animal-2a.png';
sprite.onload = function() {
  tick();
  requestAnimationFrame(tick); //вызов анимации
};

function tick() {
  if (tick_count > 10) {
    drawCat();
    tick_count = 0;
  }
  tick_count += 1;
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

function drawCat() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //очистка канваса
  sx = (sx === 288 ? 0 : sx + 96); //переброс в начало, если спрайт закончился 384 - width картинки, 384/4 =96 -шаг, на который сдвигаем
  ctx.drawImage(sprite, sx, 0, 96, 96, 100, 100, 96, 96); //отображение первого спрайта
}
```

```html
<canvas id="field" width="900" height="400">hi</canvas>
```